# Package CLI service in AppImage or Flatpak?

Tags: snap, appimage, flatpak

I'd like to package a service - e.g. nginx.  I saw [snaps could do this](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/build-a-nodejs-service?utm_source=snapcraft.io&utm_medium=buildsnapsindex&utm_campaign=tutorials#1) which is great.

Does Flatpak have any plans for a [CLI runtime](http://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/available-runtimes.html) (Command-Line Interface) available as a service?

Does Appimage have anything similar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *"Does AppImage have anything similar?"*

Yes, it is no problem to convert CLI tools into fully working AppImages.

---

## CLI AppImages from the AppImage project itself

The AppImage developers offer several of their CLI utilities which serve to create, update and run AppImages as ready-made AppImages:

---

#### appimaged

**appimaged.** This is an (optional) helper daemon which automatically creates menu entries for every new AppImage which you store in any of the monitored directories:

- Download AppImage from: https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/releases

---

#### appimageupdatetool

**appimageupdatetool.** This is a tool which search for and apply automatic binary delta updates to any AppImage which is prepared for this mechanism. (For the update mechanism to be enabled, the AppImage creator needs to have made use of the *'type 2'* AppImage format!) You can check if it is enabled by running *'`./my.AppImage --appimage-updateinfo`'*. To update an AppImage, just run:

```
appimageupdatetool -d my.AppImage   # describe where update comes from...
appimageupdatetool my.AppImage      # actually apply the update...
```

- Download AppImage from: https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageUpdate/releases

---

#### linuxdeployqt

**linuxdeployqt.** Despite its name, this cannot *ONLY* be used for Qt applications, but also for others. This tool makes Linux applications self-contained by copying in the libraries and plugins that the application uses. It optionally also generates an AppImage.

- Download AppImage from: https://github.com/probonopd/linuxdeployqt/releases

---

#### zsync2 and zsyncmake2

**zsync2** and **zsyncmake2.** These two make up the essential tools for supporting the binary delta mechanism for *'type 2'* AppImages:

- *zsync2* does the heavy lifting of downloading the deltas and patching a copy of the existing (old) AppImage into a new one. At the end of the process you downloaded a percentage of the volume of the old AppImage but have the fullly sized two AppImages (old and new) available locally. Then just test the new and keep it (alongside the old or as the only one) if you like it.
- *zsyncmake2* is the tool which creates a **.zsync* file from *ANY* file (not just an AppImage). So for *'my.binaryfile.exe'* it will create *'my.binaryfile.exe.zsync'*. That (much smaller) **.zsync* file contains the metadata about the main file which will help to identify which byte ranges have changed from the previous version. If both files are now hosted side-by-side, the *'zsync2'* CLI utility can figure out which byte-range(s) from the main (new) binary it should request for download in order to update the local (old) binary.
- Download AppImage from: https://github.com/AppImage/zsync2/releases

---

## CLI AppImages from other parties

I myself have build a few AppImages for my own use (some of which remain private for now), because they are very convenient for me: I host them on one shared directory on a Raspbery Pi in my home WLAN, but run them on multiple Linux systems where I have the shared directory automatically mounted upon each boot. This also works very well when testing Live CD ISOs.

---

#### ImageMagick v7.0.x

**ImageMagick v70.x.** I'm building new (unofficial, of course!) releases almost daily for ImageMagick7. Hopefully, this will soon be adopted by the ImageMagick developers themselves...

- Download AppImage from: https://github.com/KurtPfeifle/ImageMagick/releases

---

#### QPDF

**QPDF.** I've also built QPDF 8.0a pre-releases. Hopefully, it will not be long before the QPDF developer will release his own AppImage builds (you'll have to [check here](https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf/releases).)

This is also an example how to include your own custom 'AppRun' script into an AppImage. To see all the functionality of it, run the AppImage with the *'`--usage`'* flag.

- <strike>Download AppImage for now from: https://github.com/KurtPfeifle/qpdf-appimage-testing/releases</strike>   <== Here, there will still be *experimental* AppImages available in the future. These will cover current code developments, based on the most recent Git commits, not official releases.

**Update:** Jay Berkenbilt, the QPDF author has made the first official release of QPDF-8.0.0 which includes an AppImage as the only binary build for Linux. Get it here: [github.com/qpdf/qpdf/releases](https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf/releases). I recommend you rename the AppImage to `qpdf.ai` after download (or create a symlink with that name to it). This makes the handling of the (unwieldy for a CLI tool!) AppImage name much easier, and lets you continue to use the (old) distro-provided `qpdf` just as before. No conflict!

---

#### IPP Sample Software

**IPP Sample Software.** An AppImage with not just **one**, but **four** different CLI utilities is the *IPP Sample Software* provided by the [ISTO *Printer Working Group* (PWG)](https://www.pwg.org/) which showcases the concepts of the *Internet Printing Protocol* (IPP) and the new *IPP Everywhere* standard to come. I made ASCIIcast providing a short introductionary tutorial about this software using my AppImage, which you can watch here:

[image: asciicast]

---

#### Microsoft PowerShell for Linux

**Microsoft PowerShell for Linux.** Microsoft is distributing their new *PowerShell for Linux* as an AppImage. An ASCIIcast about this running on Debian is here:

[image: asciicast]

- Download PowerShell AppImage from:  https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases

Comment: Dude.  Awesome answer.  I'm not marking the question answered yet to leave room for a Flatpak answer - but I'll mark it answered for sure eventually.  Thanks again Kurt.

Comment: @MichaelCole: AFAIK, Flatpak doesn't support packaging CLI apps (yet?). Should this be the case, and should you learn about it through an additional answer, please make sure to edit the AppImage wiki entry about this to reflect that fact. I'll also update above screenshot then. We don't want to distribute wrong info, do we?

Comment: @MichaelCole: For more awesome info (mainly in topics/tags `[pdf]`, `[postscript]`, `[ghostscript]` and `[imagemagick]`) I invite you to pay a visit  to [my respective answers on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/359307/kurt-pfeifle?tab=profile).